# Blade template - use foreach to split array into two array based on value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm a total Laravel Blade noob and trying to do something I know how to do in JavaScript but need to do in a Blade template.

I want to loop through this object below **$site->links()->orderBy('position')->get()** and evaluate each $link->type and push to one of two new arrays based on the value. So...

```
global $navlinks = [];
global $legallinks = [];

// main loop
@foreach($site->links()->orderBy('position')->get() as $link)

// blavascript concept of what I need. 
@if($link->type == 'nav') $navlinks.push($link)
@if($link->type == 'legal) $legallinks.push($link) 

...

// Do something with new $navlinks and $legallinks arrays
```

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that looks "logics" to me, so IMO it should be done somewhere else, but in blade you can do something like this:

```
@php
$navlinks = []; 
$legallinks = [];
@endphp

// main loop
@foreach($site->links()->orderBy('position')->get() as $link) 
  @if($link->type == 'nav') @php $navlinks[] = $link; @endphp
  @if($link->type == 'legal) @php $legallinks[] = $link; @endphp
@endforeach
```

or, since `->get()` will return a `Collection`:

```
@php
  $res = $site->links()
     ->orderBy('position')
     ->get()
     ->reduce(function($acc, $val){
         $acc[$link->type][] = $val;
         return $acc;
       }, [
        'nav' => [],
        'legal' => []
     ])
@endphp
@foreach($res['legal'] as $legal) ... @endforeach
@foreach($res['nav'] as $nav) ... @endforeach
```